# How to use shared prefs/file storage to store an input by the user in the controller in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

As above; what i am currenty trying to do is use this method to store and save data; however I am not sure how to do it with a custom String that is being provided by the said user. Also how do you refresh the controller once the input has been submitted by the said person.

Furthermore, is it possible to send this into a json file and open it each time the user opens the application so as to ensure that the data that is posted there does not get lost.

Here is the sample code:

```
         MaterialButton(
            child: new Text('Touch me to go on to the next option'),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                  ),
                onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _text = (_control.text);
                _save(_text);
              });
                },
              )
```

Where _save is defined as :

```
_save(String text) async {


  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final key = 'my_int_key';
  final value = text;
  prefs.setString("text", value);
```

Is it possible to save it in such a way that the controller can be refreshed rather than throwing null errors when the MaterialButton is pressed the second time(basically redo the error) or am I allowed to create if and or statements inside a widget because I can find some but I am not sure on how to use it for this said purpose.

The load key for the above data is:

```
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final key = 'my_int_key';
  final value = prefs.getString(key) ?? null;

}
```

And is it true that this load string can be used in any screen other than the one which I am working in?

Thanks for your patience in reading this :)

Comment: Do you want the last searched keyword to be in the text field when app opened ?

Comment: @NaveenAvidi nope not the last searched keyword but to save what they entered into a storage location